# How to stop animation on tableviewcell button?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, audio

I have a button that animate when I tap it, inside that button function there is notification that generation whether the song is played or not. What I'm trying to do is "Start animation when I tap it, and stop animation when the song is playing". I'm having trouble stopping the animation.

Here is my code

```
func MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification){

    if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing)
    { //playing

        println("playinggggg")
        buttonsender?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
    else if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Stopped)
    { //stopped
        println("stopped")
    }else if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Paused)
    {
        println("paused")
    }else if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Interrupted)
    {
        println("interupted")
    }else if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingForward)
    {
        println("skip forward")
    }else if (User.postPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingBackward)
    {
        println("skip before")
    }

}


func playPost(sender: UIButton){

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,

        selector: "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:",

        name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification,

        object: nil)

    animateButton(sender)

    User.postPlayer.stop()
    var songUrl = sender.layer.valueForKey("songUrl") as? String
    println(songUrl)

    clickedIndex = sender.layer.valueForKey("index") as? Int
    sender.setTitle("II", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    User.postPlayer.contentURL = NSURL(string: songUrl!)
    User.postPlayer.play()

    buttonsender = sender

}

func animateButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let defaultDuration = 2.0
    let defaultDamping = 0.20
    let defaultVelocity = 6.0

    sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(defaultDuration,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: CGFloat(defaultDamping),
        initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat(defaultVelocity),
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
        animations: {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        },
        completion: { finished in
            self.animateButton(sender)
        }
    )
}
```

buttonsender is a global variable.
How can I stop the animation when the song playing?
Or if anybody have better solution about the loading I'll try to look at it, just give any advice.Doesn't matter written in objective c or swift.

Comment: Hi, 
In smilar way we did Play and Stop button Enabling  and Disabling. When song is playing we disable Play Button and enable Stop button.

Comment: I'm just using one button though

Comment: Yes , One button we can make Play/Stop. Button name accordingly Either play mode or Stop mode we can change by programatically.

Comment: how can I change the button name?

Comment: create  a button with tag  and make it condition. (if and else)  if tag = 0  make play mode else Stop mode then inside the conditions give Button Title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should stop

```
[CATransaction begin];
[theView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[CATransaction commit];
```